# Are node.js arrays actually hashmaps?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, hashmap, v8

To my surprise, this code actually works in node.js:

```
var arr = new Array();
// also works: var arr = [];
arr[0] = 123;
arr['abc'] = 456;
arr; // node.js: [ 123, abc: 456 ], chrome: [123]
```

I've always thought that an array stores its objects in order, only accessible by an integer key, like a std::vector in C++. However, here it's acting like a map or an object. Adding to the confusion, the same code works as expected in chrome, returning an array with a single entry, 123. I thought node.js and chrome javascript use the same internal engine, V8. What's going on here?

Comment: No, they are actually javascript arrays, with a type of 'object'!

Comment: While chrome doesn't show `456` in the console, `arr.abc` will still be `456`. It just doesn't show it in the console unless you explicitly access the variable, or `console.log(arr)`, which logs: `[123, abc: 456]` Basically, this is just a cosmetic issue.

Comment: If it's storing it under `abc` that's not really a hash map. Just a key/value array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript allows you to extend objects *on the fly*, and as an `Array` is an object you can do so.

What you are doing there is adding a new property to your array called `abc` and assigning it the value `456`.

So you could say every object in Javascript can be used as a hashmap somehow.

**EDIT**

It seems that Chrome filters the non-numeric properties of the `Array` object at dumping whilst Node dumps every user-defined property. In my opinion Node's way is better since the alpha-numeric property is available in a `for in` statement:

```
var a = [1];
a['abc'] = 2;
for (var i in a) {
    console.log(i);
}
// Prints:
// 0
// abc
```

Comment: Yea, every object can be used as hashmap, but that's not the issue. It's just an inconsistency in the displaying of the variables. That's why I reverted the edit, also: This "issue" is in fact specific to node.js

Comment: @Cerbrus In my opinion the key of the question is not how it is displayed or not by `console.log()`, but the behavior of arrays/objects as hashmaps in Javascript.

Comment: You're still not addressing the fact that the behaviour appears to be different in node versus chrome, while in fact the objects contain the same key/value pairs.

Comment: So, mind removing the downvote on my answer now you added what I answered to yours?

Answer (score 7):

The answers are right, the behaviour is maybe more understandable, if you try to display *length* of the array.

```
var ar = []
ar[0] = 42
console.log(ar.length) // 1

ar[12] = 21
console.log(ar.length) // 13

ar['ab'] = 1
console.log(ar.length) // 13 (separate property, not in array)

ar[ar.length] = 33
console.log(ar.length) // 14

ar.push(55)
console.log(ar.length) // 15

console.log(ar) // display all items specified above
//[ 42, , , , , , , , , , , , 21, 33, 55, ab: 1 ]
// which in fact really is:
// [ 42, , , , , , , , , , , , 21, 33, 55] as array and 
// special property of array object - 'ab':1
```

Answer (score 3):

While chrome doesn't show `456` in the console when you just enter `arr`, `arr.abc` will still be `456`.

It just doesn't show it in the console unless you explicitly access the variable, or `console.log(arr)`, which logs: `[123, abc: 456]`.

Basically, this is just a cosmetic issue. Node.js does show key/value properties on array objects, when you just enter the variable in the console, while chrome only shows "normal" array entries, even though both arrays actually have the same contents.

Comment: @Joel: Does this answer your question, or is something still unclear?